$\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$ does not contain a primitive 10th root of unity
I need to prove/disprove the following statement:

Every algebraically closed field $K$ contains a 10th root of unity.

I don't think the statement is true. My counterexample is as follows:
Let's take the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$ : $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$ and assume that it contains a 10th root of unity. Than there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\zeta_{10}\in\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. This means that $10\mid 2^n-1$. $2^n-1$ is clearly odd and 10 is even. An even number can not divide an odd number which means that $\zeta_{10}\notin \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\zeta_{10}\notin \bigcup_{k>0} \mathbb{F}_{2^k}=\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$.  Is this correct? Can we just conclude that it does not contain it because 10 will never divide $2^n-1$. Would $\overline{\mathbb{F}_5}$ work as well?

$\pm1$ are 10th roots of unity contained in every field. I assume you mean primitive 10th roots?

Yes, your argument works and generalizes to show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ contains a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity iff $\gcd(p, n) = 1$.

TeX note: $\newcommand\F{\mathbb F_2}\bar\F$ \bar{\mathbb F_2} probably isn't what you want; $\overline\F$ \overline{\mathbb F_2} is more common.  I edited accordingly. \ I would object a little bit to this reasoning because it doesn't really make sense to speak of $\zeta_{10}$ as something that exists a priori, and just might or might not lie in $\mathbb F_{2^n}$; rather it doesn't even lie in any field containing $\mathbb F_2$. A similar flavour: $x \mapsto x^2$ is an isomorphism on any such field (the absolute Frobenius), so $x^{10} = 1 \implies x^5 = 1$.
